# Java: Calling an object's method from another class when the object is initialized in the initialization block

Tags: java

I'm writing a Percolation program that uses that uses methods from a union-find object, which belongs to a different class. The specifics of percolation and union-find are not important for this question.

This is how I start the percolation class, where a "WeightedQuickUnionUF" object given the name "uf" is initialized. The method "uf.union" is used in this block without a problem:

```
public class Percolation{

private byte[][] grid;
private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
private int count;

public Percolation(int n){
    if (n<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    grid = new byte[n][n];
    WeightedQuickUnionUF uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+2);

    // All Grid Points are closed (=0)
    for (int row=1; row<=n; row++){
        for (int col=1; col<=n; col++) grid[row-1][col-1]=0;    
    }

    // The Auiliary top and down squares
    int aux_u = 0;
    int aux_d = n*n+1;

    // Join the auiliary squares with top and bottom rows
    for (int col=1; col<=n; col++) uf.union(aux_u, getIndex(1, col));
    for (int col=1; col<=n; col++) uf.union(aux_d, getIndex(n, col));
}
```

The problem is if when I want to use object "uf" in another method within the Percolation class. For example, I create a method "Percolates":

```
    public boolean percolates(){
    int n = grid[0].length;
    int aux_u = 0;
    int aux_d = n*n+1;
    return uf.connected(aux_u, aux_d);
    }
```

I don't get any compilation errors, but whenever this method is called at runtime, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Which, I believe it means that "uf" is a null object at this point. My question is, do I need to initialize this object elsewhere other than at the Initialization block? And why I don't have the same problem with the "grid" object? That one is also initialized at the Initialization Block.

I believe that fragments of code above are enough to understand the problem, but I post here the whole thing for completeness (code may be incorrect, I just post to give the context for the specific question above). Thanks!

```
public class Percolation{

private byte[][] grid;
private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
private int count;

public Percolation(int n){
    if (n<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    grid = new byte[n][n];
    WeightedQuickUnionUF uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+2);

    // All Grid Points are closed (=0)
    for (int row=1; row<=n; row++){
        for (int col=1; col<=n; col++) grid[row-1][col-1]=0;    
    }

    // The Auiliary top and down squares
    int aux_u = 0;
    int aux_d = n*n+1;

    // Join the auiliary squares with top and bottom rows
    for (int col=1; col<=n; col++) uf.union(aux_u, getIndex(1, col));
    for (int col=1; col<=n; col++) uf.union(aux_d, getIndex(n, col));
}

private int getIndex(int row, int col){
    int n = grid[0].length;
    if (row<1 || row>n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("row " + row + "is not between 0 and " + n);
    if (col<1 || col>n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("col " + col + "is not between 0 and " + n);
    int index = n*(row-1) + col;
    return index;
}   

public void open(int row, int col){
    int n = grid[0].length;
    if (row<1 || row>n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("row " + row + "is not between 0 and " + n);
    if (col<1 || col>n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("col " + col + "is not between 0 and " + n);

    if (grid[row-1][col-1] == 0){
        grid[row-1][col-1]=1; 
        count++;
    }

    if (col>1) connect(row, col, 'l');
    if (col<n) connect(row, col, 'r');
    if (row>1) connect(row, col, 'u');
    if (row<n) connect(row, col, 'd');
}

private void connect(int row, int col, char option){
    if (option=='l'){
        if (isOpen(row, col-1)) uf.union(getIndex(row,col), getIndex(row,col-1));
    }
    if (option=='r'){
        if (isOpen(row, col+1)) uf.union(getIndex(row,col), getIndex(row,col+1));
    }
    if (option=='u'){
        if (isOpen(row-1, col)) uf.union(getIndex(row,col), getIndex(row-1,col));
    }
    if (option=='d'){
        if (isOpen(row+1, col)) uf.union(getIndex(row,col), getIndex(row+1,col));
    }
}       

public boolean isOpen(int row, int col){
    int n = grid[0].length;
    if (row<1 || row>n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("row " + row + "is not between 0 and " + n);
    if (col<1 || col>n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("col " + col + "is not between 0 and " + n);
    if (grid[row-1][col-1] == 0) return false;
    else return true;
}

public boolean isFull(int row, int col){
    int n = grid[0].length;
    int aux_u = 0;
    if (row<1 || row>n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("row " + row + "is not between 0 and " + n);
    if (col<1 || col>n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("col " + col + "is not between 0 and " + n);
    return uf.connected(getIndex(row, col), aux_u);
}

public int numberOfOpenSites(){
    return count; 
}

public boolean percolates(){
    int n = grid[0].length;
    int aux_u = 0;
    int aux_d = n*n+1;
    return uf.connected(aux_u, aux_d);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Percolation Per = new Percolation(4);
    Per.open(3,2);
    StdOut.println("Percolates: " + Per.percolates());
}
}
```

Comment: You re-declared `uf` in your constructor, making it a local variable that is separate from the `uf` declared in the class body. Instead, initialize `this.uf`.

Comment: Change `WeightedQuickUnionUF uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+2);` to `uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+2);`

Comment: @sorifiend: Both your solution and 4castle solution worked. I can't accept it as the answer as they were left as comments, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;` is never initialized anywhere in your code so it will always cause a null pointer error.

You can fix this by simply changing the line in your `Percolation` method so that it sets the class wide `uf` instead of creating a new local `uf` variable that cant be accessed elsewhere.

To do this simply change this line:

```
WeightedQuickUnionUF uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+2);
```

To look like this:

```
uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try extending your public class from the private class. That way through inheritance you can access all the methods. Better yet specifically set that private method as accessible I believe its method.setAccessible() or something like that. First you have to get the method from the actual class you can use .getDeclaredMethod("method");  and it returns a method, so you have to declare a method object to receive it. Then you would set that method object to accessible and you should be able to use it